# 401 is returned even when bearer token is provied in asp.net core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

So I am trying to setup an authentication for my web api application. For now I am just messing around and trying to make my authorized endpoint work bearer token, but even with token I am still getting 401. I think I've tried all there is, but it still refuses to work.

Currently I have this

Code that returns a token

```
public async Task<UserResponseWithToken> Authenticate(string email, string password)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                return null;
            
            var user = await _userRepository.GetByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
                return null;
            
            if (!VerifyPasswordHash(password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
                return null;
            
            var userResponse = _mapper.Map<UserResponseWithToken>(user);
        
            var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_authenticationConfiguration.Secret));
            var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(symmetricSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
            
            Console.WriteLine(_authenticationConfiguration.Secret);
            
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                
                issuer: _authenticationConfiguration.Issuer,
                audience: _authenticationConfiguration.Audience,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
            );

            userResponse.Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return userResponse;
        }
```

Authorized endpoint

```
[HttpGet("alarms")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes=JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Configure method in Startup

```
databaseContext.Database.Migrate();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseRouting();
```

Configure services

```
services.Configure<AuthenticationConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("Authentication"));
            var symmetricSecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Authentication:Secret"]));
            var audience = Configuration["Authentication:Audience"];
            var issuer = Configuration["Authentication:Issuer"];
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                {
                    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        //what to validate
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        //validation data
                        ValidIssuer = issuer,
                        ValidAudience = audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = symmetricSecurityKey
                    };
                });
            
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder =
                    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });
```

Comment: Your `var token = new JwtSecurityToken` lines don't make sense. You need a `SecurityTokenDescriptor` instance that properly identifies the user being signed in (JWT requires a Subject).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creating token doesn't have signingCredentials, add them:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                signingCredentials:signingCredentials,
                issuer: _authenticationConfiguration.Issuer,
                audience: _authenticationConfiguration.Audience,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
            );
```

Comment: Okay, that was really silly of me. Thank you though.